# Is it possible to create and send multiple DocuSign envelopes with a single API call

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to do something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <Envelope>
        [All the good envelope stuff]  
      </Envelope>
      <Envelope>
        [All the second good envelope stuff]  
      </Envelope>
[closing XML]
```

It may be that this is not possible, can someone confirm?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean "Is it possible to create and send multiple DocuSign envelopes with a single API call":

- **YES** - Same Envelope template (server or inline) to many different recipients as "multiple envelopes"
- **NO** -  Bulk Send, Many different Templates many different Recipients

Bulk Send (REST ONLY)

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/BulkEnvelopes/BulkEnvelopes/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to send multiple envelopes as a result of one API call is to use the BulkSend node of the Envelopes: create method. [See docs.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/BulkEnvelopes/BulkEnvelopes/)

BulkSend is only available for the REST version of the Envelopes: create method, it is not available for the SOAP version.